# Wrong ImageView Is updating

Tags: java, android, xml, android-imageview

I have created an Android Baccarat game. I have six total cards displaying three for each player. Earlier I was using the app every card was displaying correctly now the players second and third card have switched positions and I have not changed anything in my code.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/PlayerCard2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/PlayerCardsTotalText"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TieBetTotalText"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:contentDescription="@string/PlayerCard2Image"
        android:src="@drawable/b1fv" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/PlayerCard3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/PlayerCardsTotalText"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/PlayerCard3Image"
        android:src="@drawable/b1fv" />
```

This Is the XML code for the players cards. PlayerCard2 & PlayerCard3 are the ones that have switched.

```
PlayerCardImage2.setImageResource(deckOfCards[PlayerCard+ generateSuit()]);
```

This is the java code that updates the images based on randomly selected number in an array.

I have tried switching the positions of the cards and I still get the same result.

```
PlayerCardImage1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.PlayerCard1);
    PlayerCardImage2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.PlayerCard2);
    PlayerCardImage3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.PlayerCard3);
```

This is where I reference the images from the activity.

Comment: Could you please show the code where you get the `PlayerCardImage2`variable?

Comment: We can only suggest to make sure that `PlayerCardImage2` is referencing  to the correct `ImageView`. double check your `findViewById(R.id.PlayerCardxxxxx)` statements. Else post your all `onCreate()` code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the autogenerated `R` class is messed up, which happens occasionally.
You should clean your project - in Eclipse: Project -> Clean... -> Check your project. This will also trigger a recreation of `R` and should fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you. That solved my problem I would have never seen that. Any specific reason why this might happen?